# Docker expose port only to VPN

Tags: docker, vpn, port, pi-hole

I'm setting up a DNS filter using Pi-Hole and OpenVPN on a VPS. Pi-hole is running in a Docker container and exposes port 80 for its web interface. How do I expose this port only to traffic originating from the VPN (10.0.8.0/24), and not to the internet?